# How to upload image to DAM using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, aem

How can I upload image to DAM from standart HTML input? I've tried to google it but i've couldn't find anything usefull.

Now I know just that I should use [AssetManager](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/AssetManager.html) and [Asset](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/dam/api/Asset.html) classes but I can't find out how to upload images to DAM using these classes. Or should I use something else?

Answer (score 2):

Using a standard HTML form with a file input it is possible to upload a file directly into the DAM.  Use a form something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="http://localhost:4502/content/dam/geometrixx.createasset.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" size="20" name="_charset_" value="utf-8">
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Change the path in the form action from `/content/dam/geometrixx` to whatever DAM location you wish.

If you select a file named my.gif, it will create an asset in the DAM at `/content/dam/geometrixx/my.gif`

It will go through the normal workflows to give you the various asset renditions also.